# accessing attribute from other model in my search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes

I'm a newbie and struggling a little with this:

I have two models: User & Job, the relationship is as follows:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my jobs index view I have a search form where I want to locate jobs by address (ie: look for the User's address),

```
<%= form_tag(jobs_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :address, params[:address] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', class:'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

which is one of the user's attribute:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "remember_digest"
  t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
  t.string   "activation_digest"
  t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
  t.datetime "activated_at"
  t.string   "reset_digest"
  t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
  t.float    "latitude"
  t.float    "longitude"
  ***t.string   "address"***
  t.string   "phone"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
end
```

In my JobsController, how do I point to the User's attributes? ie: User's address ? This is the index function I have for now:

```
def index
  @jobs = if params[:address]
    Job.where('address LIKE ?', "%#{params[:address]}%").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
  else
    @jobs = Job.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 4)
  end
end
```

But obviously I'm not getting any thing when doing a search.

Thank you for your guiding advice in advance. Rodolphe

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
Job.joins(:user).where(users: { address: address }) }
```

Comment: Hello Fredius,
Sorry to be a pain but I've tried to implement this solution but I'm not going anywhere. Could you please more specific ? Where do I put this exactly in the controller? I'm not looking for a nanny here, I'm struggling to find the right syntax. Thanks!